# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'" logged in Sentry

Tags: reactjs, sentry, unexpected-token

I am using Sentry in a React application.

Sentry keeps logging the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'". In the file in which the error occurs, it indicates a line in which there isn't any ';' token. The error occurs for mobile phone users only (Android and iOS).

Here's a screenshot of the stack trace:

[Sentry stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNbv4.png)

Here's a screenshot of a user's device information:

[User device information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRdni.png)